# catkin:command not found

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ros-kinetic Ubuntu-16.04

I used ros yesterday,but today when I input `$roscore` to lauch my ros environment,the system points that :
The program`roscore`has not been installed.
You can use the following command to install:
`sudo apt install python-roslaunch`

I followed with these prompts, finally I find my `catkin`commond is not found,and I should install it.

But I input "catkin" in the termial ,then use "tab",there echo some commands ,but no catkin .
Is that means I already installed it?
because I use `sudo apt install ros-kinetic-catkin`,it tells me is the latest version.

```
$ catkin_

catkin_create_pkg          catkin_package_version
catkin_find                catkin_prepare_release
catkin_find_pkg            catkin_tag_changelog
catkin_generate_changelog  catkin_test_changelog
catkin_init_workspace      catkin_test_results
catkin_make                catkin_topological_order
catkin_make_isolated
```

I tried to install catkin by this command `sudo apt install catkin`,it points I should install `python-catkin-pkg` first,so I did.
However,even I installed that, when I want to install catkin package, it still said I need install python-catkin-pkg.

And I do add this Environment variables
`source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash`  to ~/.bashrc ,and I have sourced it.

The really confused thing is ! I already used it to create some workspace,and it works well!
I really do not know why I can use `roscore`  yesterday ,but today I can't.
Maybe I did some changes in the system,but I really don't know!

I really need help,Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/284983/catkin:command-not-found/) by [Summer](https://answers.ros.org/users/33945/summer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2018-03-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I rewrote my ~/.bashrc file,
added `source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash` to  ~/.bashrc,and sourced it .
It works.

---

Originally posted by [Summer](https://answers.ros.org/users/33945/summer/) with karma: 18 on 2018-03-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0